# сервис для скачивания файлов или какой либо другой вариант

Tags: файлы, download

Имеем лаунчер, который скачивает файлики размером от 50мб до 2ГБ, при первом запуске общий объем ~3ГБ, далее не большие апдейты от 50 до 500мб.
Сейчас все висит на паре вдсок, с хорошим каналом, но они начали дохнуть(скорости не хватает на всех).

Посоветуйте какие либо варианты. (Если CDN, то посоветуй какой именно...)
Так же есть идея организации аля "торрента", но тут проблема с тем что файлы довольно часто обновляются.